# pg_dump fails to create a backup when running from System User in Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a pg_dump through a scheduled task in windows. I have two batch files. One creates the task. The other one runs the pg_dump. Even though the pg_dump works with the current user with no problem, I have to run the pg_dump as a System because I want it to run even if the user is not logged on. Unfortunately, to run a task when a user is logged off, you have to run it in System user and that doesn't work for pg_dump. I couldn't see any error. It simply creates an empty backup file and after that, pg_dump keeps on running, blocking future runs.

Part of my pg_dump code is the following.

```
%PG_BIN%pg_dump -h %PG_HOST% -p %PG_PORT% -U %PG_USER% -F c -b -v -f %BACKUP_FILE% %DB%
```

Part of my Schtaks code that creates the task.

```
SchTasks /Create /SC MINUTE /mo 30 /RU "SYSTEM" /TN "Database Backup" /TR "%SCRIPT_DIR%backup_db.bat"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for the problem. I had to change the run as user to the current logged in user after first setting it to SYSTEM. This will prompt the user to enter the password. This change doesn't remove the radio selection on **"Run whether the user is logged on or not"** and pg_dump works with the current user. The nice thing is, the code runs silently. The code I added under the schedule task creator batch script is the follow.

```
SchTasks /Change /TN "Database Backup" /RU "%username%" /RP *
```

Comment: ,Even you can backing up of PostgreSQL Server in Windows Environment in two https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Windows. FYI

Comment: Of course, I have used the code from there. But it doesn't talk about Windows Task Scheduler issues.